# Me sale un error al intentar ejecutar un sentencia sql, SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, sqlite3

estoy haciendo un programa que me haga menús. Para ello estoy utilizando un entorno virtual de python 3.9 con virtualenv y sqlite3. Para que no se repitan los platos estoy intentando actualizar una columna booleana a true. Para ello estoy utilizando este fragmento de código:

```
cursor_obj.execute(f'UPDATE platos SET usado = 1 WHERE idPlato = {id_plato_1}')
```

Pero me sale un error de syntaxis:

```
File "/Users/miguelflorez/Developer/myProjects/python/menu_maker/main.py", line 50
    cursor_obj.execute(f'UPDATE platos SET usado = 1 WHERE idPlato = {id_plato_1}')
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Gracias.

Comment: A veces, esos errores aparecen por ejemplo por olvidar cerrar un parentesis o una comilla en la lineas anteriores. ¿Revisaste que hayas cerrado todos los parentesis, comillas, corchetes, etc en las lineas anteriores?

Comment: ¿Cómo te fue con lo que te propuse?

Comment: No encontré ningún paréntesis, comillas... sin cerrar, pero gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En teoria tu codigo no tiene ningun error puede que el error provenga de la linea inmediatamente anterior o simplemente sea un error de indentacion sin embargo intentemos algo diferente.

Te voy a recomendar sacar el str de la sentencia y lo pongas en una varaiable aparte para utilizar otro tipo de formato.

```
statement = 'UPDATE platos SET usado = 1 WHERE idPlato = {id_plato}'.format(id_plato=id_plato_1)
cursor_obj.execute(statement)
```

cuentame si te funciono

Un saludo :)

Comment: Ya no me sale ese error, pero me ha salido otro nuevo. sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked

Comment: Cuando la base de datos sqlite te devuelve ese error posiblemente es porque haces demasiados procesos al tiempo y no se procesan bien o puede ser un proceso que es muy pesado para bd, te recomiendo utilizar un batch para no sobrecargar la bd.

Answer (score -1):

Intenta cerrar con un `;` tu sentencia:

```
cursor_obj.execute(f'UPDATE platos SET usado = 1 WHERE idPlato = id_plato_1;')
```

Comment: He probado ha poner ; al final pero no me funciona.